# Minimize $f(A,B)$ s.t. $\text{exp}(A)^T \text{exp}(B)=J_K$

Tags: optimization, constraint, lagrange-multipliers, constrained-optimization

I have a function $f(A,B)$ that maps a pair of two (tall) matrices, $A$ and $B$, to a scalar cost that I want to minimize. $A$ and $B$ both have $K$ columns. I also want to impose a set of equality constraints, s.t. $\text{exp}(A)^T \text{exp}(B)=J_K$, where $J_K$ is the $K\times K$ matrix of ones. In other words, for every pair of columns in $\text{exp}(A)$ and $\text{exp}(B)$, the dot product of these columns must equal 1.

How would you approach this problem? I've been looking into different kinds of constrained optimization techniques but I haven't managed to get a good sense of which (if any) would be the most promising for my setting.

Edit:
To clarify, the $\text{exp}$ function is applied entry-wise to these matrices. An example of a solution that satisfies the constraints is:
$$
A = \log \left( \frac{1}{12} \begin{bmatrix}
11 & 1\\ 
11 & 1\\ 
1 & 11\\ 
1 & 11 
\end{bmatrix} \right),  \text{ } B = \log \left( \frac{1}{12} \begin{bmatrix}
11 & 1\\ 
1 & 11\\ 
11 & 1\\ 
1 & 11 
\end{bmatrix} \right)
$$
(where the $\log$ function is also applied element-wise.)

If it helps, you can assume that $f$ has the following form:
$$
f(A,B) = -(\sum_i {\vec{x}^T}^{(i)} A\vec{y}^{(i)} + {\vec{x}^T}^{(i)} B\vec{z}^{(i)}   )
$$
where $\vec{x}$, $\vec{y}$, and $\vec{z}$ are all strictly non-negative column vectors, which happen have the further property that $\vec{x}^T\vec{1}=\vec{y}^T\vec{1}=\vec{z}^T\vec{1}=1$ (i.e. the sum of the entries of each vector equals 1 - not sure if this is relevant but I'll mention it just in case it is). $i$ indexes separate instances of these vectors that we sum over.

Comment: Please explain what the function "$\exp$" is for non-square matrices.  Would it perhaps be exponentiation of each entry separately?  Regardless, the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality indicates your situation simply cannot exist for $K\gt 1$ unless all the columns of $A$ and $B$ are the same, so please exhibit a non-trivial example of such matrices for $K\gt 1.$

Comment: Yes, $\text{exp}$ is applied to each entry separately - I have clarified this in my question. There definitely are solutions that satisfy the constraint, and I have provided an example.

Comment: Thank you: your example clearly reveals how I misinterpreted your question.  I had thought you wanted "every pair of columns in $\exp(A)$ and $\exp{B}$" to mean "every pair of columns in $\exp(A)$" *and* "every pair of columns in $\exp(B).$"  But why introduce $\exp$ at all?  It is superfluous because it can be absorbed into $f,$ about which you make no assumptions whatsoever.  How one approaches an optimization problem depends very much on the assumed properties of the function one is optimizing.  It would also help to indicate how your question may be of any statistical interest.

Comment: I use $\exp$ because it implements the further constraint that $\exp(A)$ and $\exp(B)$ be strictly positive (assuming we're working with real numbers only). I'll add some information about the function, in case that helps.

Comment: It helps immensely because it reveals $f$ is a linear function of $(A,B),$ which is a huge simplification.

Comment: Ruben van Bergen, could you help others to gain some intuition behind this problem, by explaining the origin where it comes from. What sort of problem follows these boundaries and cost function?

Comment: Can the equality constraint with the $J_k$ work if you have more that two columns in $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: It can work with more columns than I gave in the example, but then you need more rows. I think in general the number of columns across $A$ and $B$ together cannot exceed the number of rows in each. I will try to add some more background on the problem as you requested.

Comment: @Ruben yes you are right. I realized this later as well (when I 
asked the question I was still stuck in a simplistic view). All the the vectors that have a particular value for the dot product with a particular column $A_i$ are in a $n-1$ dimensional plane that is perpendicular to $A_i$. So all the $B_i$ must only need to be on the intersection of those planes, and there can be infinitely many columns.

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting some work I've done on your problem, this is not a full answer but I think it almost covers it all.

### Loss function

$f$, as you wrote it, is linear. This is good enough, but that equation can be developed a bit to simplify the problem. Let's define two new matrices:

$$
W_A= \sum_i \vec{x}_{(i)}\vec{y}^T_{(i)}; \qquad W_B= \sum_i \vec{x}_{(i)}\vec{z}^T_{(i)}.
$$

$W_A$ and $W_B$ have the same shape of $A$ and $B$ and provide the weight for each of their elements, for computing $f$. Actually, the utility function is just the weighted sum of all elements in $A$ and $B$.

### Parametrization

Let's call $A' = exp(A)$ and $B' = exp(B)$. You can of course optimize $A$ and $B$, with $f$ strictly linear, but a very complex bounded domain, or optimize $A'$ and $B'$, with the addictional constrain of positiveness, but still a simpler domain (linearly bounded). Of course from $A'$ and $B'$ you can immediately find $A$ and $B$.

I would rather do the latter: even if this way $f$ is not linear anymore, it's still trivially derivable. A quick google search for a viable solver brought me [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01585529).

### However...

If you multiply any row of $A'$ to some (strictly positive) value $k$, and you divide the corresponding row of $B'$ by the same value, $A'^T B'$ is unchanged (constraints respected), but $f(A, B)$ may do change, and if it does it changes linearly with $k$, because of the properties of logarithm. This means that $k$ either is undetermined or diverges.

Comment: I think that $k$ is undetermined because the sum of the elements in $W_A$ and $W_B$ are equal (that further property makes it equal to the number of $i$)

Comment: you are right!.